# voltage control and frequency control

Tags: power-supply, mains

I am learning on frequency control and voltage control. I am just starting the topic, so I am in little doubt.

1. Does voltage control has any relation with reactive power compensation?
2. How is frequency control associateed with power control?

If possible, could anyone please explain to me in simple words about voltage and frequency control.

Thanks in advance

Comment: control of what??

Comment: Are you referring to PWM control?

Comment: @Lelesquiz  ans Neil_UK   i am talking about power system control

Comment: Did you learn anything Pravin?

Answer (score 1):

Power factor control is largely due to the dominant motor loads one industrial machines.

There are many methods of utility power generation system power factor and phase-frequency control systems to adjust  supply to meet demand.

Since the grid cannot store much energy except for brief intevals, the system must supply the load in real-time.

Nuclear reactors are run at 100% output while being only 50% efficient with heat loss transferred to available water at a temperature about 5’C above the body of water. While all the other sources must make up the difference in demand load with power factor being one of the variables..

Adapting + or - reactance to by phase control to maximize pf correction comes at a cost of conduction losses reducing the generators output.  Passive L and LC harmonic tuned filters are common place to optimize pf depending on harmonic content.

A method uses passive (manual or ) auto-switched Cap banks made of polypropylene dielectric while older versions were oil filled capacitors.

> The concept is to provide conjugate matching of the grid and distribution source reactance to the load reactance while have a resistive impedance relative to rated load impedance measure in Z per unit or Zpu (%) of about 10 in order to limit fault currents to 10x rated load.
>    But since it is dynamic, diurnal and seasonal it is a fairly complex control system.

Shunt Reactors and Cap banks both rated in kVARs to shift phase.  Both can be fixed with tap switches or remote switched depending on location dynamics.

Generators can be electro-mechanically remote-controlled to increase current phaser angle as coordinated by the utilities and Regional Power Authority by also adjusting frequency down if supply cannot meet demand but then need to make up for lost cycles in low demand periods with higher frequency over the regional specified tolerances.

Governors may be electromechanical, or electronic Grid Tied Inverters (GTI) which usually pf =1 but can be remote programmed to adapt if necessary.

There are libraries full of books, magazines and papers on the web thru Archive.gov, Google Scholar and MIcrosoft Research that are better read for the details on all the factors that must be considered for stability, optimization and more cost effective ways to control line reactance, load reactance and fault protection.

Here in Toronto, we have the luxury of state-of-the art control systems with remote monitors for each distribution line for power, balance, power factor, fault, redundancy control, instant fault re-routing, service isolation protection, and realtime home power utilization every minute with charts available to each consumer thru our Alectra home page to look for patterns per hour or day of the week or month of the year to examine energy use.

Comment: Thanks TOny for your answer .... i guess you are talking about motor control ,i guess . I was querying about power system distribution line - voltage control and frequency control in transmission line  buses and line  .

Comment: What do you know? Need to know and why? And where have you researched?

Comment: so much thanks for your answer ... in your answer you are saying about power factor control  , am i right ? ... Is power factor control related to voltage control or frequency control ? i am not able to correlate it with frequency and voltage control , i am sorry if i am dumb

Comment: **reactance  controls pf** and frequency of grid slows down (slowly) from excess load then rises to recover to stay within tolerance.  Voltage control is done by tap changers